# Local Basis in a topological vector space.

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

i'm studying local basis, but i'm stucked, because i already understood what a local basis means, if $\mathscr{B}$ is a local basis of $x \in X$, where $X$ is a topological vector space, then

1. $x \in B$, for all $B \in \mathscr{B}_x$.
2. If $U$ is an open set $U \in \tau$, such that $x \in U$, then $\exists B \in \mathscr{B}_x$ such that $x \in B \subseteq U$.

now i would like give another definition to local basis in terms of basics, my idea is:
Let $\tau$ vectorial topology, such that is given by a basis $\mathscr{B}$, so the collection $\{x + B |B \in \mathscr{B}\}$ is a local basis for $x$, but i don't know if the basic $B \in \mathscr{B}$ must cotains $x$,i already now that $\{B| x \in B, \in \mathscr{B}\}$ is a local basis of $x$, i'm trying to relate this with the fact that $x + U$ is an open set, if $U \in \tau$, any help will be really appreciated, thank you so much.

Comment: What properties do the elements of $\mathscr B$ have? I think you might find that it's an assumption that elements of $\mathscr B$ are all neighborhoods of $0$, i.e. $x\in B$ which then implies $x\in x+B$.

Comment: well i don't know if they have a propierty,   i'm trying to formulate it by my own, but i already proved that if $0 \in \mathscr{B}$, then is a local basis

Comment: Ah so can you edit your question to give your precise definition of local basis?

Comment: I already edit it